# How to put a Unix Date to an input with ui-mask for DataTime

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an input element:

```
<input id="inputInicio" required name="inputInicio" ui-mask="99/99/9999 99:99:99" 
       ng-model="captura.inicioReq" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" class="form-control">
```

And I want to initialize it with a default value. The default value is `captura.inicioReq`. This variable is an unix (from `Date.UTF`) format.

**How can I configure the value to show on input?**

When I set the ui-mask and placeholder, the value disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!

I created a directive (attribute) named validar-data and I added it on input I'd like to use:

```
<input id="inputInicio" required name="inputInicio" ui-mask="99/99/9999 99:99:99" validar-data ng-model="captura.inicioReq" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" class="form-control">
```

This attribute require and the ng-model. With the model I bind it's formatters and parsers, so I was able to control the incoming and out value format.

```
requisicaoManual.directive('validarData', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        priority: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',

        link: function($scope, $elm, $attrs, ngModelController) {
            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(entrada) {
                var data = String(entrada).replace(/[A-z]*/g, "");
                var momentJsDate = moment(ngModelController.$viewValue, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss", true);
                ngModelController.$invalid = !momentJsDate.isValid();
                if (momentJsDate.isValid()) {
                    data = momentJsDate.valueOf();
                    return data;
                }
                return data;
            });

            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
                data = moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
                return data;
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

More information on: 
http://alexperry.io/angularjs/2014/12/10/parsers-and-formatters-angular.html
 and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Thanks